# What does "void SomeFunction(int, void*)" mean?

Tags: c++, function

I am trying out some OpenCV and are on a tutorial for a Canny edge detector [Example](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html).

In this tutorial, there is a function declared like this:

```
void CannyThreshold(int, void*)
```

and then called like this from inside main;

```
CannyThreshold(0, 0);
```

I don't understand the purpose og the (int, void*) part of the declaration since none of these arguments are used in the CannyThreshold funtion.

Why is it simply not just declared like this?

```
void CannyThreshold();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note this line in the example:

```
createTrackbar( "Min Threshold:", window_name, &lowThreshold, max_lowThreshold, CannyThreshold );
```

Here, `CannyThreshold` is passed as a callback argument to `createTrackbar`. The signature of `createTrackbar` requires the callback to accept these two arguments, and so `CannyThreshold` does, even if it has no use for them.

Comment: Thank you. So, the CannyThreshold is called from within this createTrackbar function every time the slider changes as I understand? Why is it then also called below with the arguments (0,0). Is that necessary?

Comment: @eirikaso That's because the function also displays something (last line). And the easiest way to reuse this display code for the initial display is to simply call the function with dummy arguments.

Comment: I have moved the CannyThreshold definition into a seperate .cpp file and connect them using a header file. The only call left in the main function is the "CannyThreshold(0,0)" line. Is it a bad idea to move the "createTrackbar" into the "CannyThreshold" definition in the seperate .cpp file? Seems to be working but I'm not sure how wise it is

Comment: That's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the function as

```
void CannyThreshold();
```

that is the same as

```
void CannyThreshold(void);
```

In other words, it's a function that takes no argument.

If you want the function to take arguments, but never use those arguments, you must still declare the types of the arguments.

Comment: Note that this only applies to C++. In C, on the other hand, an empty argument list on declaration means an unspecified amount of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This is supposedly because this function is a *callback*, hence its signature is enforced by whatever API is used (here: OpenCV).

A callback is a name given to a function when this function is *registered* into an event system to be called later, when something happens. A function registering a callback is called a *functor*, it takes another function as argument, and do something with it. Exemple:

```
using callback_t = void(*)(int);
void register_callback(callback_t cb);
```

If you want to define a callback to be called (back) by `register_callback`, it needs to be a function taking an `int` and returning `void`, even if you don't need the integer. So the following definition is possible:

```
void my_callback(int) { std::cout << "done\n"; }
register_callback(my_callback);
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to read up upon callback functions as it's not crystal clear to me how they work